# Insert Multiple Checkbox in multiple rows in database using laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

i want to insert the multiple checkbox values in multiple rows at same time in  database. i get the value of checkbox and when submit the form it stores null value in database. i think i m unable to pass the checkbox value from the view to controller.... 
Here is my Controller code:

```
`public function create(Request $request) {`
        `$treatment_id = json_decode(Input::get('treatment_id'), true); 
        //assuming you use json to submit the multiple countries`

 $user_countries = array();
 foreach($countries as $country)
 {
     $treatment_id[]=new Price(array('treatment_id'=>$treatment_id));
 }

    //save the countries into the DB

    $user->prices()->saveMany($treatment_id);
    $count=$request->input('counter');
    for ($i=1; $i<=$count; $i++) { 
        $prices= new Price;
        $hospital_id=$request->input('hospital_id');
        $category_id=$request->input('category_id');
        $treatment_id=$request->input('treatment_id');   
        $price=$request->input('price');   

        $prices->hospital_id=$hospital_id;
        $prices->category_id=$category_id;
        $prices->treatment_id=$treatment_id;
        $prices->price=$price;

        $prices->save();
      }
    return view('admin.viewprice');
}
```

and here is my view/blade code: in this page I am fetching the input checkbox value name or price section using ajax in `productname` class section

```
 <form role="form" action="{{route('createprice')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="1" /> 
                <select class="form-control" name="hospital_id">
                @foreach($hospitals as $key=> $hospital)
                <option value="{{$hospital->id}}">{{$hospital->hospital_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
               </select>
               <select style="width:200px;" class="productcategory form-control" id="prod_cat_id" name="category_id">
    <option value="0" disabled="true" selected="true">--Select--</option>
    @foreach($categories as $key=> $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{$category->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
    </select>
    <div class="productname" id="add_schedule">

     </div>
     `Ajax Request`
     op+='<option value="0" selected disabled> Chose Product</option>';
                for(var i=1; i<data.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('counter').value = i;                     
                      op+='<div class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="treatment_id[]" value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].treatment_name+'</div>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+'<div class="col-md-4"><input type="text" name="price[]" /></div>';
```

I don't know where I making mistake ... if anybody have solution then please help me ....

Comment: What are you seeing when you do `dd($treatment_id)`